Why isn't there an "exterior algebra"-like structure imposed on the tangent spaces of smooth manifolds?
I'm going through Nakahara's book "Geometry, Topology, and Physics" (my background is physics, sorry if this question is obvious to math backgrounds). In chapter 5, after defining smooth manifolds, tangent and cotangent spaces, and tensor fields of type $(p,q)$ on these manifolds, he begins defining $r$-forms. He goes through the whole procedure of defining the wedge product, the exterior and interior derivative, etc., such that the constructed space $\Omega^r$ is a particular subspace of the type $(0,r)$ space $\mathcal{T}^0_r$, which has the additional structure imposed by the exterior algebra (maybe using the word subspace is inappropriate since it has extra structure).
The construction itself I understand. what I don't get is why this is only done for the dual-type space. What's stopping us from defining a nice algebraic structure on tensors of type $(q,0)$ and doing the same thing? If nothing is stopping us, why isn't it useful compared to $r$-forms? I mean, the tangent and cotangent spaces are dual to each other right? I'd like to know the motivation behind this asymmetry in treatment.

The wedge product of differential forms is special because differential forms pull back along smooth maps and this pullback is compatible with the wedge product. There is no analogue of this for vector fields or multivector fields.

Qiaochu's comment is the best answer. The natural direction is contravariant, so we work with the exterior algebra of the cotangent space.

When you say "there is no analogue", do you mean the pushforward is incompatible with a wedge product on the tangent space, or that it's incompatible with any reasonably defined product?

For any finite-dimensional real vector space $V$, one can definitely consider the exterior powers $\bigwedge^k(V)$, which are defined by their "universal property". These are important as well (though people often gloss over them for quicker presentations). One can show that the dual of this vector space is $\left(\bigwedge^k(V)\right)^*\cong \bigwedge^k(V^*)\cong \text{Alt}^k(V;\Bbb{R})$.
So, if we were to cheat a little, we could incorporate double duality into the definition and define without any mention of universal properties: $\bigwedge^k(V):=\text{Alt}^k(V^*;\Bbb{R})$, the space of $k$-fold alternating maps out of $(V^*)^k$.
A place where these spaces show up is for example in Hamiltonian mechanics, when considering the Poisson bivector field (i.e $\pi$ is a smooth section of $\bigwedge^2(TM)$ where $(M,\omega)$ is the symplectic manifold representing the phase space of our system).

But I’d say that if you can, it’s best to avoid the exterior algebra of the tangent space. It’s too easy to get lost in all the normalizing factors. About 90% of differential geometry and 100% of the introductory material can be done this way.

@Deane but the issue isn’t that we’re dealing with the tangent space vs cotangent space, it’s that we’re trying to treat the exterior powers as subspaces rather than quotients of the tensor spaces

The way I stay sane with this stuff is the following: I define $\bigotimes^kV^$ as the space of all $k$-linear functions of $V$ and $\bigwedge^kV^$ as the subspace of alternating $k$-linear functions. I then view $\bigotimes^kV$ as the dual to $\bigotimes^kV^$. If so, then the natural dual of the subspace $\bigwedge^kV^\subset\bigotimes^kV^$ is the quotient space $\bigotimes^kV/(\bigwedge^kV^)^\perp$. Is this equivalent to your answer? So for me there is an asymmetry between the definitions of $\bigwedge^kV^*$ and $\bigwedge^kV$.

Indeed, nothing is stopping you. Sometimes we use wedge products of tangent vectors too. For example, the Riemann tensor can be considered as an operator sending a bivector $\alpha \in \Lambda^2 T M$ to a linear operator on $T M$. One of the reasons they are less useful because of integration: if you scale the shape by a factor of $\lambda$, then the volume of the shape will be scaled by $\lambda^n$, not $\lambda^{-n}$. So among $\Lambda^n T M$ and $\Lambda^n T^* M = \Omega^n M$, only one is suitable for us to define volume. And if you go through the calculation you will see the suitable one is $n$-forms $\Omega^n M$.
